# Code Editor Syntax Highlighter with Multiple Instances for JavaScript and HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, codemirror, code-editor

I have tried CodeMirror for creating a simple code editor with syntax highlighting using simple javascript and html, but the problem is that in my project I have multiple  html Tabs, and on for each tab I need a CodeMirror instance.

I don't have any problems creating multiple instances, the problem is that I have only one button that when is clicked needs to read the content of the CodeMirror instance that is in the current Tab and send its content to an Http service, so I can’t find the best way to find the correct CodeMirror instance when the button is clicked.

So I what recommendations could you give me ? or is a better idea to try with other libraries like Ace or Prism for code highlighting?. Thanks.

I have tried using localStorage to save instances of CodeMirror but it retrieves me an error of Converting circular structure to JSON.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! There may not be a one-size-fits-all way to do this; however, one option is to store each CodeMirror instance in a dictionary, using the tab name or tab index as the key. Then, when you press the button, figure out which tab is active and get the right CodeMirror instance for it.

Comment: Hi ! I have tried using localStorage to save instances of CodeMirror but it retrieves me an error of Converting circular structure to JSON.

Comment: So, when you say multiple tabs, you mean multiple browser tabs? And you need them to talk to each other, because the button only exists in one of the tabs?

Comment: By the way, if you can show what you have tried, that will help others point you to a solution more quickly.